# Negative and insulting

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What do you call someone who is constantly negative, cynical about the world around him and can't help but nitpick and find a way to insult everyone around him?

Comment: Without using obscene language?

Comment: ELU does not exist to forever serve up new ways to help people insult other people.

Comment: Related: [Can anything be done about mean-spirited requests for terminology?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4842)

Comment: This question seems a bit different -- certainly more challenging.

Comment: Let's try this: contemptuous control freak.

Answer (score 2):

Wishing to be light hearted about it and not to give ammunition to those who may wish to insult others, I recommend A.A. Milne's gloomy character "Eeyore". (I have corrected my previous typo in the name)

Comment: It is speet _eeyore_, like the sound a donkey makes.

Comment: In American English, what a donkey says is spelled 'hee haw'. Since AmE pronounces final 'r's, 'eeyore' doesn't sound like a donkey in the US.

Comment: @Mitch, it sounds like you haven't read Winnie the Pooh yet.  You're in for a treat.